# Cannot read property of undefined, looking for object property

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the `dots` array from each object. However I keep getting cannot read property dots of undefined.

```
 let events = fetchEvents[this.state.selectedDay || selected];
```

in my component I am using:

```
      <EventCalendar
         events={events.dots || []} 
...
```

I'm my `EventCalendar` component, `this.props.events` is `undefined`

```
  render() {
    const {
      width,
      virtualizedListProps,
      initDate,
      formatHeader,
      upperCaseHeader = false
    } = this.props;

    const allDayEvents = this.props.events.filter(
      event => event.allDayEvent == 1
    );
```

`fetchEvents` array:

```
  2019-03-06: {dots: Array(2), disabled: false, selected: true, selectedColor: "#00CCCB", customStyles: {…}}
    2019-03-07: {dots: Array(1), disabled: false, selected: true,
```

Comment: Are you sure that this.state.selectedDay or selected contain a valid date?

Comment: `events` is null or undefined in `{events.dots || []}`

Comment: I believe you're not calling the intended JSON Object. Have you tried `events['2019-03-07'].dots?`

Side Note: I would not use the date with a hyphen as your *key*. You could remove the hyphen just to have digits instead since each key will be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're not calling the intended JSON Object. Have you tried events['2019-03-07'].dots? Side Note: I would not use the date with a hyphen as your key. You could remove the hyphen just to have digits instead since each key will be unique. Please refer to image below.

[image]

Comment: Yes I have tried that - some of the dates might not exist so I need to set the array as empty

Comment: So does this not get the dots' value..? I'm a little confused on that because your current code will always return undefined because you're trying to get the `dots` of `event`, which doesn't exist, and not of a JSON object of `event`.